# Verificar calidad y el estado de la señal del celular

Tags: android, android-studio, get, servicio, switch

Estoy haciendo un login offline, el cual detecta si el celular no tiene internet y se activa un switch de manera automática y con la ayuda de sharedPreferences puedo logear sin problemas y sin internet.

Pero ahora quiero modificarlo, para que cuando la señal sea muy muy bajita se active de igual manera mi switch y funcione el modo OffLine (con poquita señal en el celular).

La cuestión es que no se que método o que debería de usa????? . Les muestro el código que utilizo

```
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                 //aca no hace nada porque si tiene señal el celular
    } else {
                 Switch.setChecked(true); //activo el switch
                 Switch.setClickable(false); //no dejo que nadie mas lo vuelva a mover por seguridad
                // aca ejecuto tódo mi código porque es la parte que no tiene señal el celular
```

Lo que ahora necesito es que el celular reconozca o verifique que hay poca señal para que se active mi switch de igual manera. Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es posible:

"Cuando la señal sea muy muy bajita se active de igual manera mi switch y funcione el modo OffLine (con poquita señal en el celular)."

Las clases que actualmente se tienen en el SDK determinan si tienes (`isAvailable()`) o no señal y si puedes establecer conexión (`isConnected()`).

La forma para revisar si tienes conectividad y es posible establecer conexión es:

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Entonces se podra ver la forma de que mi proceso se este demorando mucho al tratar de iniciar sesión y ponerle un mensaje que me diga "Su conexión no es estable,Desactive sus datos para acceder al Modo OffLine" y que al salir este mensaje me interrumpa o ponga fin el proceso anterior que esta intentando logear... habra algo que se pueda hcer asi???????

Comment: Oh! si tu proceso esta demorando, puede no ser por la conectividad, que realiza tu proceso? esta en un Asnctask?

Comment: La aplicación para iniciar sesión utiliza internet... pero los que la utilizan se van a pueblos lejanos que a veces no hay señal o hay muy bajo, es ahí donde al iniciar sesión comienza a dar vueltas intentado ingresar pero al no haber señal o muy bajita se queda ahi dando vueltas.... alli se le hizo un login offLine que se activa si no hay internet(nada), pero si hay bajo internet el login "normal" es el que sigue dando vueltas para tratar de ingresar....y como no se puede identificar si hay baja señal quiero ponerle un msj en el momento que esta dando vueltas que diga lo explicado arriba.

Comment: En pocas palabras, lo que quiero es medir el tiempo que esta dando vueltas el boton de iniciar sesión, y ahi finalizarlo a la fuerza practicamente.

Comment: Como se puede cerrar un botón del todo ?? por código